# Glossary spanning multiple pages with different titles

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the glossaries package for my thesis and need to customize the output of printglossary to meet my university's formatting requirements.

When printed, the number of abbreviations is so large that it spans two pages in total (this may reach three later on). Unfortunately, the title is only printed on the first page and the title is blank on the following pages. I need to have "LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS" on the first page and "LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS (continued)" on the following pages.

Right now, I think I only have three options:

1. Figure out how to print different titles on each page while using printglossary. I already looked at the documentation and did not see anything, but I could have missed it.
2. Use a custom style provided by one of my university's departments, which does the special title formatting over multiple pages, and figure out how to use printglossary without inserting a new page when called. I tried using the samepage environment and redefining glsclearpage, both with no luck.
3. Use the same custom style but manually build the glossary. This is not preferred due to the extra maintenance and sorting but will do if absolutely necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this can help someone else. I read through the `glossaries` package documentation again and decided to try and make my own custom style.

Inside of `\newglossarystyle` I renewed the `\glossarypreamble` command and simply called the `\listofabbreviations` as defined in my university's custom style. This suppressed the extra page and allowed me to get the continued headers.